Faulty Show/hide Labels and diagrams
I am attempting to clean up some road name labels manually in a map I am creating. There are too many of the same ones along the roads. I have been through everything in label properties: Rendering, placement, formatting and it is getting somewhat better with tweaks, but I still need to hide some of the labels manually.
However the tool 'Show/hide Labels and diagrams' seems faulty. I shift + clik the label and nothing happens. It understands that there is a label (see photo below), but it does not disappear.

I do not get an error. However none of the label-moving tools work either. When i try to move a label i do get an error. It says: 'The label X/Y coloumns "LblX" and "LblY" do not exist in the layer".
Can anyone explain to me if they are experiencing the same problem or if the problem seem to be specific to my layer or version of QGIS. When I look through google I can see people have had the same problem throughout the years, but I cannot find any recent problems.
I will add that my version of QGIS is 3.28 Firenze. I cannot update the version, as it is locked by my work computer.
